# Traduction de « Rogue Nation »

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais

Dans le sous-titre d'un film Américain, on a *Rogue Nation*; le [sens](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/rogue) en anglais est relié à la *différence* de statut qu'entraîne, pour une nation en l’occurrence, la non adhésion au cadre normatif international, et aux *inquiétudes* que ça suscite. Au Québec on a traduit par : *La nation rogue*. Et l'emploi de la majuscule en début de mot varie dans la presse : parfois avec rogue uniquement, parfois avec les deux mots. Enfin rien n'indique qu'on use du mot *rogue* de manière particulière. Au [dictionnaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rogue) ([2](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rogue/69721?q=rogue#68967)) on a, à l'adjectif, *dédaigneux, hautain, méprisant* etc. Quant au [substantif](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rogue/1) ([2](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rogue/69722?q=rogue#68968)), c'est l'hyperonyme pour l'*œuf de poisson*<sup>1</sup>, comme au sushi du coin, quand on n'a pas plus précis... En résumé le mot *rogue* n'a pas le même sens dans les deux langues.

Comment pourrait-on traduire ici *Rogue Nation* de manière usuelle et qui rende plus fidèlement le sens des mots anglais ? Sur quel sens de quel mot s'appuie-t-on ?

---

<sub>1. Ce peut-être aussi, lit-on, l'appât d’œufs de poisson (la morue en particulier; *Larousse* ajoute « salés »), servant à la pêche des poissons de mer (sardine).</sub>

Comment: Merci pour les réponses; on a des options ! Je voyais ça sous l'angle usuel et je n'imaginais pas retrouver ça en terminologie ([1](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=ROGUE+NATION), [2](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26511004) ) ! On y retrouve une variante que j'aime bien, _l'État renégat_, similaire aux réponses ; mais ça relève de la préférence personnelle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'expression « *[Rogue state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_state)* » (qui a émergé aux États-Unis dans les années 1980, et s'est [surtout répandue au début des années 1990](https://books.google.fr/books?id=nWirUpPFDZMC&pg=PA277&dq=%22rogue+state%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22rogue%20state%22&f=false)) est habituellement traduite par [État voyou](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tat_voyou). On a la même paire d'expressions en anglais et en français, tant dans le sens le plus courant d'État au ban des nations (État dont le comportement a conduit beaucoup d'autres États à suspendre leurs relations diplomatiques et économiques), que dans le sens que l'on trouve quelquefois d'une expression péjorative envers le concept même d'État.

La variante « *Rogue nation* » est [beaucoup moins courante](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Rogue+state%2CRogue+State%2CRogue+nation%2CRogue+Nation&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CRogue%20state%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CRogue%20State%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CRogue%20Nation%3B%2Cc0). Je ne crois pas qu'il y ait d'autre nuance que celles que l'on peut faire entre *state* (état) et *nation* (nation). Donc traduire par « nation voyou » est raisonnable (ou éventuellement « nation voyoue », mais le mot *voyou* a du mal à s'imposer comme adjectif, il a tendence à rester un nom apposé et donc à ne pas prendre de marque de genre). Sur [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=english&query=+%22rogue+nation%22), la seule traduction de « *Rogue nation* » est « État voyou », sauf un « pays de maroufles » qui paraît mal placé à mes oreilles de Français.

Comment: « Maroufle » est parfaitement français, simplement désuet. Le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/maroufle#Nom_commun_1) cite un exemple chez Alexandre Dumas en 1820. Si tu pensais qu'il s'agissait d'un terme québécois, il semblerait que [seule la variante féminine du nom](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8976484) - qui n'a rien à voir avec le mot dont nous parlons ici - soit utilisée chez nos cousins.

Comment: @Chop J'aurais dû dire « de Français au XIXe siècle ». Oui, c'est du français, mais je n'ai jamais entendu personne l'utiliser.

Comment: Hormis dans de vieux textes (ou des textes imitant volontairement un style ancien), oui, il est vrai que je ne l'ai jamais rencontré.

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR → mes propositions

> Nation incontrôlable

ou

> Nation rebelle

ou encore

> Nation renégate

(merci à [Larme](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/3016/larme) pour la dernière idée)

### Détail de la réflexion

#### Recherches

En sus de [la réponse de Gilles](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14564/7224), j'ai rapidement regardé [quelles traductions proposait WordReference pour *rogue*](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/rogue) ainsi que [ses définitions sur Wiktionary<sup>1</sup>](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rogue)<sup>2</sup>.

Premier constat sur WordReference : le seul cas d'utilisation de *rogue* en tant qu'adjectif s'applique à un animal, mais sa traduction est étonnamment proche du contexte décrit dans la question.

En consultant la [section « adjectif » du Wiktionary pour *rogue*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rogue#Adjective), on trouve en effet que cette traduction initialement réservée aux animaux a plusieurs définitions par extension, dont la troisième avec cette citation :

> rogue (adj.)
>   3. *(by extension)* Deceitful, unprincipled.
>   **2004:** [Chris Wallace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Wallace_(journalist)), *Character: Profiles in Presidential Courage*
>
> > In the minds of Republican hard-liners, the "Silent Majority" of Americans who had elected the President, and even Nixon's two Democrat predecessors, China was a gigantic nuke-wielding **rogue** state prepared to overrun the free world at any moment.

#### Traductions selon le Wiktionary

Le Wiktionary propose également [des traductions pour cet adjectif](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rogue#Translations_2). Pour la définition que j'ai retenue, c'est la suivante qui est mise en avant :

> French: *sans scrupules*

Cette traduction ne me semble cependant pas adapté. D'après la question :

> le [sens](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/rogue) en anglais est relié à la différence de statut qu'entraîne, pour une nation en l’occurrence, la non adhésion au cadre normatif international, et aux inquiétudes que ça suscite.

Dans ce cadre, une des autres propositions du Wiktionary me paraît plus adaptée :

> French: *incontrôlable*

#### Autre idée

Le premier mot qui me vient à l'esprit en cherchant à traduire *rogue* est toujours *rebelle*<sup>3</sup>. Malgré la connotation de ce mot, [sa définition](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rebelle) me semble correspondre au contexte donné dans la question (voir la locution « esprit rebelle » par exemple).

On peut aussi penser à « renégat » pour celui qui renie ses principes (« *The spy went rogue.* » ; merci à [Larme](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/3016/larme)).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> J'utilise volontairement le nom anglais du site, puisque je me suis basé sur sa version anglaise et non sur le Wiktionnaire. Inutile de corriger.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> J'imagine que la traduction de *nation* ne pose pas de problème et que le mot est présent davantage pour donner un contexte. Je me concentre donc sur *rogue* pour cette réponse.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> Ceci vient probablement de l'idée que je me fais d'une traduction possible du nom de jeu [Star Wars: Rogue Squadron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rogue_Squadron). Je n'ai malheureusement pas réussi à trouver son nom québecois. Le livre *Rogue Squadron* a subi la même traduction malheureuse que le titre cité en question et s'appelle en France [*L'Escadron Rogue*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Escadron_Rogue) (à moins que *rogue* ne soit pas utilisé ici comme un qualificatif mais comme un nom, ainsi que le suggère la capitalisation dans le titre).</sub>

Comment: "... sécurité de l'ONU, le gouvernement américain, l'Union européenne, le Vatican, bref en défiant le monde entier, Sharon et ses semblables font d'Israël ce qu'on appelle en anglais «a rogue state», **un État rebelle**, un État qui ne respecte ni ses ennemis, ni ses amis, un État qui attache sa survie à l'exercice de sa force brutale, rien d'autre." This quote, found in in Reverso's Context feature, lends support to your inclination towards 'rebelle' (& Gilles' towards 'Etat') while also providing possible meanings of the notion in French. Regardless, +1 to you both, & the question as well.

Comment: For what it's worth, here is the link to the quote mentioned above:  http://mobile-dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/rogue

Comment: @RiguefortUltraquaillette Il semblerait que les noms de jeux vidéo échappent à la loi 101, bien que [celle-ci impose une version française du jeu](http://www.ledevoir.com/societe/actualites-en-societe/153675/tous-les-jeux-video-vendus-au-quebec-devront-etre-traduits-en-francais) (jouer à une version québécoise pour un métropolitain peut d'ailleurs s'avérer déroutant lorsqu'on ne s'y attend pas).

Comment: J'aime bien « rebelle », plus proche de « renégat », qui selon ma traduction personnelle et en vu du sujet du film, colle sûrement mieux avec « rogue spy » (ou « he went rogue », comme souvent dans les films).

Comment: « Renégat » ! Comment puis-je à chaque fois l'oublier ? Merci @Larme, je me suis permis de l'intégrer dans la réponse. :)

Answer (score 1):

Mon très vieux dictionnaire bilingue *Robert et Collins* m'a donné l'adjectif « malhonnête » qui me parait bien convenir et résumer ce que vous proposez tous. J'ai entrepris cette recherche suite à une discussion avec un de mes élèves sur ce film *Mission Impossible, Rogue Nation* sorti en France fin 2015. Je ne pense pas que ce sous-titre évoque quoi que ce soit aux français; pour les canadiens français, leur habileté en anglais les sauve. Je comprends maintenant pourquoi ce sous-titre a été conservé en Europe, habituellement les titres sont encore « francisés », les français ont encore beaucoup de progrès à faire en anglais, c'est sûr!!